# Iframe Auto Resize in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, resize, size

Im using the following code at functions.php to resize my IFRAMES

```
function add_youtube_size($youtubehtml) {
   if (strpos($youtubehtml, "<iframe" ) !== false) {
        $youtubesearch = array( 'width="460"', 'height="310"');
        $youtubereplace = array( 'width="600"', 'height="338"');
        $youtubehtml = str_replace($youtubesearch, $youtubereplace, $youtubehtml);

        return $youtubehtml;
   } else {
        return $youtubehtml;
   }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_youtube_size', 10);
```

But this code only edit the size of iframes with 460 x 310.

There Is any way i can change that line `$youtube search = array( 'width="460"', 'height="310"');` to get any possible sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change it

```
$youtubesearch = array( 'width="460"', 'height="310"');
$youtubereplace = array( 'width="600"', 'height="338"');
```

In those lines change both **width** and **height** to what you need but it important that your search video also should available in your written width and height